# How to disable Android emulator console log debug message in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, apple-m1

When using Android ARM emulator in Flutter, a lot of no useful debug message are spewing out. (See screenshot below)

How to disable Android emulator console log debug message in Flutter?

[image]

Comment: you want to Removing the DEBUG Banner on emulator screen?

Comment: No. I want to remove console log as shown in screenshot.

Comment: Switch off the emulator, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I think your `solution` could be `folding` up lines with same `substring` you may go through below process. It may help you
In **Android Studio**

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Click **Editor**
3. Select **Console**

here you will find line saying

```
fold console line that contains :
```

Just add the line to this list and check whether it helped you or not.

**Ref.** Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off outputs like this:
[image]